# Geogebra import into latex doesn't work

Tags: external-files, import

I created this file :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\newrgbcolor{zzttqq}{0.6 0.2 0}

\psset{xunit=1.0cm,yunit=1.0cm,algebraic=true,dotstyle=o,dotsize=3pt 
0,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}

\begin{pspicture*}(-4.3,-2.6)(7.06,6.3)

\psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,xAxis=true,yAxis=true,Dx=1,Dy=1,ticksize=-2pt 0,subticks=2]{->}(0,0)(-4.3,-2.6)(7.06,6.3)

\pspolygon[linecolor=zzttqq,fillcolor=zzttqq,fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.1](1,2)(3,2)(3,4)(1,4)

\psline[linecolor=zzttqq](1,2)(3,2)

\psline[linecolor=zzttqq](3,2)(3,4)

\psline[linecolor=zzttqq](3,4)(1,4)

\psline[linecolor=zzttqq](1,4)(1,2)

\begin{scriptsize}

\psdots[dotstyle=*,linecolor=blue](1,2)

\rput[bl](1.08,2.12){\blue{$A$}}

\psdots[dotstyle=*,linecolor=blue](3,2)

\rput[bl](3.08,2.12){\blue{$B$}}

\psdots[dotstyle=*,linecolor=blue](3,4)

\rput[bl](3.08,4.12){\blue{$C$}}

\psdots[dotstyle=*,linecolor=blue](1,4)

\rput[bl](1.08,4.12){\blue{$D$}}

\end{scriptsize}

\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

He gives me 58 errors. I have not realla clue why these errors apperar.
Perhaps it has problems with the colors.
Do i need to include the tikz package or sth else?

Comment: Your example works fine for me with `latex`, but not with `pdflatex`.

Comment: You are exporting to PSTricks; export to TikZ

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Thx for the quick answers.

Comment: So i have to say Geogebra that it should not create PSTricks but a tex file?

Comment: What do ihave to do that i use latex, but not not pdflatex? Sorry i am still quite new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Compile with `latex` instead of `pdflatex`. If you use a graphical editor such as TeXMaker, TeXShop, TeXWorks, TeXnicCenter etc., you have to find the button to change this. In the terminal you can simply enter `latex <yourfilenamehere>.tex`. `latex` will output a `.dvi` file, then you have to convert to `.ps` then to `.pdf`. (`latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf`)
2. Tell GeoGebra to export to TikZ. That will compile directly to PDF.

Comment: Hi, i have the same problem again. MY file is now very big. Could this be a problem?

Comment: As soon as i import it to latex and try to compile i get 101 eoors and then it stops. No matter if i export via pstricks or PGF/Tikz

Comment: Three possibilities come to mind. 1. Your document has some other error. Try to compile without the figure. 2. You don't have the necessary `\usepackage{tikz}` or `\usepackage{pstricks}` in your preamble. 3. When using PSTricks you cannot compile with `pdflatex`, only `latex`.